# Definition of data types in Typescript arrow functions

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions

I stumbled across piece of the following code

```
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = data => console.log(data);
```

I rewrote it in the form I understand

```
  const onSubmitFunction = ( data: IFormInput ):void => console.log(data);
```

But still I wonder what did mean the *:SubmitHandler<IFormInput>* after the first colon. Submit handler is defined as a type

```
export type SubmitHandler<TFieldValues extends FieldValues> = (data: TFieldValues, event?: React.BaseSyntheticEvent) => any | Promise<any>;
```

Thank you.

Comment: `SubmitHandler` is a generic type. What specifically are you confused about?

Comment: about "why there are any types defined before the = sign". i am new to the arrow function, so I see there is input datatype, output datatype but what is that SubmitHandler type? Is it input, is it output?

Answer (score 1):

> I rewrote it in the form I understand... But still I wonder what did mean the `:SubmitHandler<IFormInput>` after the first colon

That *is* what it mean!  It means exactly what you rewrote.

The expression `const x: Y =` means “x is a constant of type Y”.

The expression `const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> =` means “onSubmit is a constant of type SubmitHandler, which is to say, the generic type SubmitHandler instantiated with the type IFormInput, which in turn means a function that takes a value of type IFormInput and returns nothing.”

If you had simply written `const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);` then the compiler could have inferred that it was function (because of the `=>`) and that it returned the same type as console.log (nothing), but it would have no way to know what “data” meant.

**Edit:** I was asked to clarify what I mean by “the type of a function”.

A value (or a constant, expression, or variable) can be of function-type, meaning:

1. it is in fact a function, and not a string or array or whatever
2. it takes a tuple or list of arguments, of some particular types
3. it returns a value of some particular type

The OP’s example, `SubmitHandler` is probably written something like this:

```
 type SubmitHandler<T> = (t: T) => void
```

meaning “a value of type SubmitHandler of T is a function that takes one argument, of type T, and returns no value”.

Comment: yeah, here I am confused "onSubmit is a constant of type SubmitHandler,".For me function  has input and output data type. But how can function has some type? Except of output type and input type.

Comment: @Puser — [response in edit]